# Elasticsearch Java High Level Client Dependency refuse to work with Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am having trouble with dependencies for Elasticsearch High Level Java Client 6.2.2 in Android Studio 3.0.

I have alot of duplicate files in my META-INF directory and sub-directories. I've tried using packagingOptions, doesn't work. Other things that doesn't work

- Using default compiler instead of D8
- Use older version of Gradle.
- Turned off instant run.
- Advanced profiling is not on.
- Invalidate/manually delete cache.
- my app/libs is empty.
- I can't exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' because I'm using the client.

The only thing that will get the app to run is change implementation 'org.elastic... to compileOnly. But this means I cant call the functions at run time.

I am new to android and this is driving me nuts. Should I start poking around in libraries folder .idea\libraries and changing some of these paths? Could this be where the problem is?

**Here is the Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com. .myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-
client:6.2.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.9.1'
}
```

**This is the error I'm currently getting. With bad formating**

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
Failed to process C:\Users\mmmmmm\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
```

2.1\org.elasticsearch\elasticsearch\6.2.2\16b3f7a7a31b89144723eb85c0583234842f68
4\elasticsearch-6.2.2.jar

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process 
C:\Users\mmmmm\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
```

2.1\org.elasticsearch\elasticsearch\6.2.2\16b3f7a7a31b89144723eb85c0583234842f684\elasticsearch-6.2.2.jar